# Playing AVAudioPlayer and SystemSoundID

Tags: objective-c

I am building a game with Sprit Kit and I'm using a continuous loop of a sound using AVAudioPlayer in the didMoveToView method. But I'm also using four other sounds using SystemSoundID, which have been created outside of the didMoveToView method. The problem is when I play my game the sound playing using AVAudioPlayer seems to drown out all the other sounds I have using the systemSound. I could use AVAudio for all of the sounds which does seem to work fine, but it also slows my game down a little. Just wondering if there is an alternative or fix for this? Forgot to mention that it only seems to be a problem when i plug earphones in but it works fine when played without.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view


NSURL *playSound = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"jungleSound" ofType:@"wav"]];

NSError *error;

player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:playSound error:&error];

[player play];

player.numberOfLoops = -1;  //Continuous play//
```

And outside of the method

```
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Jump2" ofType:@"wav"];
SystemSoundID soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath], &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);


NSString *soundPath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"squish" ofType:@"wav"];
SystemSoundID soundID2;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath2], &soundID2);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID2);


NSString *soundPath3 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Powerup3" ofType:@"wav"];
SystemSoundID soundID3;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath3], & soundID3);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning the volume up in ringer and alerts under settings solved this problem.